# Adding item to collection navigation property in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I have a `Project` class that contains a collection of `AppUsers`

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please enter a project name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please enter a project description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppUser> ProjectManagers { get; set; }

    public bool UserIsAlreadyPM(string userId)
    {
        foreach(AppUser user in this.ProjectManagers)
        {
            if(user.Id == userId)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My `AppUser` class

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    //add properties here later
}
```

I want to be able to have the capability for any particular `AppUser` to be within the `ProjectManagers` of more than one `Project`. I add the `AppUser` to any `Project.ProjectManagers` via my repository method:

```
public void AddProjectManager(int projectID, AppUser user)
{
      Project proj = context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectID);
      if(proj != null)
      {
          proj.ProjectManagers.Add(user);
          context.SaveChanges();
      }
}
```

This works the first time the `AppUser` is added to a `Project.ProjectManagers` collection. However, this will not work if I attempt to add them to any other `Project.ProjectManagers` collection. If they are assign to any subsequent `Project.ProjectManagers` I get an primary key error because they are already in the database under a different project.

"SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AppUser'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AppUser'. The duplicate key value is (xxxx)."

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @John yes, I'm using EF and Core 2.1

Comment: @coolhand Add your `AppUser` model class to the question.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I've edited the question to add the `AppUser` class

Comment: @coolhand What you have added does not make any benefit. Add the `AppUser` class all property too.

Comment: @TanvirArjel there are no additional properties at this time. It's merely a placeholder for the time being until I want to add properties as the application progresses. I added it just to clarify that there is nothing unusual about the class. Thank you for your help on fixing this with your answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please write your code as follows:

```
public void AddProjectManager(int projectID, AppUser user)
{
        Project proj = context.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectManagers)
                              .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectID);

        if(!proj.ProjectManagers.Any(pm => pm.Id = user.Id)) // <-- Here check that `AppUser` already not in Project's `ProjectManagers` collection
        {
            AppUser appUser =  context.AppUsers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id== user.Id);
            if(appUser != null) // <-- Confirm that the `AppUser` you are trying to add to Project's `ProjectManagers` collection is already exist in database
            {
                proj.ProjectManagers.Add(appUser);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Once I refactored my repository this worked. However, the additional checks on `AppUser` are already performed in my controller before calling `AddProjectManager()`